# Креативный и творческий — в чем сходство и различие этих слов?

Tags: лексика, семантика

```
— Какой же это перфоманс! В чем здесь творческое 
  начало? Креативность нужна во всем. 
— Творчество и креативность — это не одно и тоже.
— Это как раз одно и тоже: create — создавать, творить.
```

Почему **нет взаимопонимания** при общении двух пользователей языка?  Существуют **словари,** где есть определения этих слов, тем не менее они по-разному понимают их значение. (С другой стороны, как **создаются** эти словари, но это уже другая тема.)

Я считаю, что это практически **синонимы**, просто в слове ***креативный*** есть элемент новизны, что меня и привлекает. Синонимы часто нужны для того, чтобы не повторять в речи одно и то же слово. А мой собеседник видит **оценочное** значение в слове ***креативный***, причем очень оригинальное.

Но по словарю между этими словами **больше сходства**, чем различия, а оценочности я не вижу.

И вопрос: Когда нужно говорить **творческий, а когда креативный**? Или это все-таки одно и то же.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

**ТВОРЧЕСКИЙ**, -ая, -ое. 1. к Творчество. Т. процесс. Т. путь художника. Т. вечер кого-л., чей-л. (торжественное собрание, посвящённое творчеству одного человека). 2. **Свойственный человеку, наделённому способностью творить, созидать что-л.** Т-ие способности. Т-ая натура. Т-ое воображение. Т. ум. Т-ие планы. Т. подъём. 3. **Самостоятельно создающий что-л. новое, оригинальное;** **созидательный.** Т-ая сила. Т-ая молодёжь. Т-ое содружество единомышленников. Т. труд. Т-ая интеллигенция. Творчески, нареч. Т. мыслить, работать. Т. подойти к решению

**КРЕАТИВНЫЙ,** -ая, -ое; -вен, -вна, -вно. [англ. creative от лат. creāre - порождать, создавать]. Книжн. 1. Творческий, созидательный, новаторский. // Способный порождать новое, творить. 2. Предназначенный для возбуждения воображения, фантазии. **Креативность**, -и; ж.

Comment: Предназначенный для возбуждения imagination противопоставлено Т-ое воображение. Креативный - порождающий, побуждающий, творческий - рожденный, созданный, совершённый. Взгляды с разных концов на вещи и процессы.